# Find out if an object was created in a certain other class?

Tags: java

```
public class Ability{

    ItemStack i;

    public Ability(ItemStack i){
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public class OtherClass{

    onEvent(Event e){
        if(e.getItemStack() is an ItemStack from the Ability class){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

You hopefully noticed that this was pseudo code but it represents what I'm trying to achieve. This would turn my really big switch statement that also ties my project to Java 7 reliance into something much more concise and versatile. I need a way of finding whether or not ItemStack objects passed through my event listener originate from my Ability class.

Comment: Is it ok if the solution modifies the Ability class?

Comment: @import-this Let's see what you've got. I fear that the need for this implies poor project design on my part...

Comment: If you need this sort of information, just use a parameter you pass into the constructor. Trying to achieve it in some automated way is a recipe for messy and unreliable code. (FWIW, you could potentially do it by creating an exception and looking at its stack trace[1]... really not recommended though!)

Comment: This sounds like an indication of bad design. Code the Ability/ItemStack classes to indicate explicitly what you need.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know. It's an indication of poor design. The general technique of having a function behave differently depending on who called it is called 'state orientation' and was deprecated in the 1970s if not before.

Comment: I was thinking of a static index in the Ability class as a quick and dirty solution, but keeping all these references around has already given me second and third thoughts. What are you going to do inside the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be the Event class to have a source element much like the Swing event classes, ex http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource().

But try to figure out a solution where the event handler would be independent on the source. 
Usually there is a better way and this coupling between the listener and the source can be avoided...